# AES encryption and decryption using Web Crypto API

Tags: javascript, security, encryption, cryptography, webcrypto-api

I've found two codes in Github for encrypting and decrypting data (Strings) using Web Crypto API, and the problem is that I'm not a cryptography expert so I want to know your opinion of the security of these codes? Are they secure enough to rely on them for susceptible data?

Encryption:

```js
async function encryptMessage(key) {
    let encoded = getMessageEncoding();
    // The iv must never be reused with a given key.
    iv = window.crypto.getRandomValues(new Uint8Array(12));
    ciphertext = await window.crypto.subtle.encrypt(
        {
            name: "AES-GCM",
            iv: iv
        },
        key,
        encoded
    )
    .then(function (encrypted) {
        console.log(new Uint8Array(encrypted));
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

Decryption:

```js
async function decryptMessage(key) {
    let encoded = getMessageEncoding();
    let decrypted = await window.crypto.subtle.decrypt(
        {
            name: "AES-GCM",
            iv: iv
        },
        key,
        ciphertext
    )
    .then(function (decrypted) {
        console.log(new Uint8Array(encrypted));
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });
}
```

If you can make any improvement to the code for upgrading its security, I will appreciate that.

Comment: AES-GCM is a good choice, the code looks IMHO good (long random iv/nonce is used). However the most important part is missing: How are the crypto keys managed (where are they stored)? Usually security problems start when you use good crypto in an insecure way.

Comment: Thank you for your time! This will be used as client-side encryption, so the key is held by the client (symmetric encryption) and not end-to-end encryption where there is a public key and private key. So it looks good for symmetric encryption?